# crawling result is null

Tags: beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

im doing the crawling about r6s

like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


bsURL = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/Spoit.GODSENT"
respinse = requests.get(bsURL)
html = bs(respinse.text, 'html.parser')

level = html.find_all(class_='trn-defstat__value')

print(level[0])
```

print Result-->

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">
439
</div>
```

I only want to print numbers.

so i did print(level[0].text)

Result -> none

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: try it wit `level[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.string` instead of `.text` like this:

```
print(level[0].string)
```

Output:

```
439
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Doing this would benefit u and the other people who view this question.